# Recent apps List in kotlin

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android application that can display all recent apps and button to close them all. But how can I get the recent app list. Is there any api or method to get the list of recently opened apps.

Thanks for help!

Comment: This has not been available for years, for privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

No , this not been available
this ability is blocked for privacy

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32793249)